# How do you delete old ubuntu partitions?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, 15.04, gparted

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 in order to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.10. After installing, Ubuntu 15.04 created a new partition. I wanted to merge the two partitions and if you can suggest ways on how to do this, please do. Here is a screenshot of GParted Partition Editor:

[image]

Should I do a reinstall of Ubuntu 15.04 or can I use GParted in order to merge /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda4? I also want to keep the files found in the partitions even if I have already backed them up. I have not noticed anything that gives me a manual installation of Ubuntu 15.04 while installing. Please remember that I do not have much experience in Ubuntu so please make procedures simple.

Comment: If you backup everything in those partitions ,you can directly delete those partitions@Julie

Comment: But I have heard that deleting the /dev/sda7 (which is labeled as "/") will cause complications

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge two partitions. You can only delete those partitions and combine them. So here is my opinion:

1. Backup your important data
2. Boot from Live DVD.
3. Delete both the ext4 partitions and reinstall Ubuntu 15.04

You want to keep your files without deleting them, but that is not possible. You are rewriting the partitions. So expectedly, the files will be lost. So be careful and take a backup before proceeding.

Comment: Even if /dev/sda7 is like... the Ubuntu OS Partition? Wouldn't I encounter problems if I delete that?

Comment: @JulieAnneGala Precisely. Thats why you need to take backup of your data and reinstall it. No way to merge them.

Comment: Alright. Are there any other system problems that I would encounter?

Comment: Since you will be formatting the partitions, your OS and data will be lost. Apart from that, there are no other complications. In case, if you have  partitions other than the two Ubuntu installations, such as Windows, do not accidentally delete them. Be cautious in deleting & formatting the partitions. That is all

Comment: I will try it eventually. Thank you very much!